# Error creating Vue.js project, Unsupported URL Type

Tags: vue.js, npm

When i try to install a vue js project, i got this error message

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-101-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/za/node_modules/.bin/npm" "install" "--loglevel" "error"
npm ERR! node v12.18.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12

npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type: npm:vue-loader@^16.0.0-beta.3
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/za/Bureau/Laravel/belenus/npm-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error
```

My npm version is 6.14.7, @vue/cli is 4.5.3, node is 12.18.3 and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934852/vue-cli-3-command-failed-npm-install-loglevel-error) for other possible solutions.

Comment: I try `npm cache clean --force` and  `npm cache verify` but it's did not work for me

Comment: @Zekura Have you tried other solutions mentioned in the linked post?

Comment: I also try `npm config set unsafe-perm true` and editing the ~/.vuerc from "useTaobaoRegistry": false to true but it's did not work for me too

Comment: Yes make sure you have the latest versions. NPM as well

Comment: I install node js 14.8.0 but it's steel doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today. The `npm:vue-loader` looked like a typo, so I did a search and found it in the package lock file. Linked to the cli-service dependency I **was** using.
I removed this line from my package.json file

`"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",`

As I wasn't using that dependency any more.

If you need that dependency you might have luck down grade the cli-service. Otherwise you'd have to log a bug with the vue team

Answer (score 0):

All of previous answers didn't work for me.
But i found chine's answer - and it's working:

1. `npm install npm@latest -g`
2. `npm install -g npm`
3. `npm install`