# Mac Vue Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps

Tags: javascript, macos, vue.js, frontend

I'm on Mac.
Everytime I vue create project, it shows error:
'Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps'

[image]

```
Error: command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/executeCommand.js:138:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
```

Is it about mac access? How to do with it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934852/vue-cli-3-command-failed-npm-install-loglevel-error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.